# File permissions: kernel or file system?

Tags: files, permissions, kernel

When we say "file permissions" are we referring to something that's inside the kernel, or a function of the file system? What layer determines where those permissions are stored. I'm confused at what level file permissions exist. Can someone help clarify the boundary?

I know how `chown` `chmod` work from the User-Perspective, but I don't know how they're implemented, or what actually throws the "Permission denied" error

```
touch foo
chmod 000 foo
cat foo
cat: foo: Permission denied
```

Can someone take me through the process of how the kernel, file system, io, and bits fit into that sequence above.

Comment: The filesystem layer certainly determines where they're stored on disk (because it determines where *everything* is stored on disk) but I don't think that's what you're trying to get at. Do you mean where the enforcement happens, or where they can be modified, where run-time data structures live, or something else?

Comment: I mean my model is that the a file is a contiguous stream bytes, what decides if the permissions are stored in the header or the footer and how do permissions models that don't line up like VFAT get virtualized to something like unix permissions or does the file system answer questions about who can open what with UID or GID?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I tried to clarify above.

Comment: I gotta run, if no one answers I'll start to dive through source tomorrow and I'll try to self answer it

Answer (score 3):

The best one-word answer to this question is either *both* or *[mu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mu#Etymology_2)*.

In the Unix operating system design, the filesystem functionality is provided by the kernel. So file permissions come from the kernel, and are enforced by the kernel.

Inside the kernel, there's a subsystem that handles accesses to files. Permissions are enforced by that subsystem. Subsystems don't have a clearly defined boundary, they're a human construction to understand the structure of the system. It is actually useful to separate the part of the kernel that handles accesses to files into two parts:

- the virtual filesystem (VFS), which handles accesses from application and parses paths;
- individual filesystem drivers, which manage access to specific filesystems that store information in a particular format.

Each filesystem driver decides how it stores and retrieves permissions. The VFS layer doesn't care: its job is to dispatch requests to the correct drivers. Filesystems for disk files store the permissions somewhere on the disk, if they support them at all. Filesystems for disk files that follow a traditional Unix design store permissions with other metadata in a file's [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). Network filesystems ask the server what the permissions are, if the protocol supports permissions. If the format or protocol doesn't support Unix permissions, it's up to the driver to make up something, for example by reporting the same permissions for all files. In-memory filesystems such as procfs and sysfs store permissions in a data structure in memory or calculate them on the fly. [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) calls a function in the program that implements the filesystem, and so on.

Note that both the VFS layer and the filesystem driver contribute to determining whether an access request is granted. A request may even involve multiple filesystem drivers if it involves a path that traverses mount points (e.g. if `/foo/bar` is a mount point, then an access to `/foo/bar/qux` requires querying one filesystem for the traversal of `/` and `/foo` and another for the traversal of `/foo/bar` and `/foo/bar/qux`). The details of the split can vary depending on the Unix variant, but typically the VFS layer relates the file permissions with the calling context and may apply other restrictions (read-only mount, frameworks such as SELinux, etc.), and the individual filesystem may apply additional restrictions (e.g. for a network filesystem, the server can always say no).

Comment: The filesystem functionality may be provided by userspace, not only by the kernel. And kernel provides filesystem functionality not only in UNIX.

Comment: @ajeh There are libraries that provide filesystem functionality for applications using them (e.g. GVFS) but they don't do anything with permissions (they wouldn't be able to enforce any permissions since it's just library code with no isolation). All filesystem functionality that's in any way remotely concerned with permissions involves the kernel. The kernel may delegate some of that functionality: as I mention in my answer, that's FUSE (or it can happen indirectly through network filesystems). As for what happens outside Unix, it's off-topic on this site.